# What is the name of this theme?

Tags: gnome, themes

Hello AskUbuntu commumity!
I'm new here, and i want to ask something.

I saw this repo on github to make the gnome blurry and I like the theme (not the blur) shown in the screenshots

This is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Github repo: https://github.com/yilozt/mutter-rounded

Can anyone give me the name of theme please (not the extension to make the windows blurry).

Thanks.

Comment: Arch Linux is not supported here

Comment: @nobody The question is about the name of the theme (which can be installed in Ubuntu, and is on topic). OP did not say that he/she is running Arch. Have a look at the discussion here. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19907/implementing-three-vote-close-on-ask-ubuntu#comment44601_19907

Comment: @Someone I do not use GNOME, but is not mutter-rounded itself the theme? I did not get why you deleted your answer.

Comment: I want a theme to make the titlebar like shown in screenshot

Comment: I don't understand why my question is not clear

Comment: The titlebar of the windows

Comment: The OS name is shown in the picture it is not Ubuntu

Comment: If it's a theme, i need the name of the theme, if it's another distro I need the name of that distro

Comment: Arch Linux dosen't have a theme like this, so it's a custom theme

Comment: mutter rounded is not a theme, it's like an extension which works on arch and ubuntu ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133609/discussion-between-bilal-bentoumi-and-someone).

Answer (score 1):

### Mutter Rounded

**Name**: Mutter rounded.

**Description**: It's a WM + GTK theme to create the background of the applications blurry to resemble a Mac OS effect.

**Package-name**: `mutter-rounded.deb`

**Supported OS**: Ubuntu 21.10; Fedora; Arch etc...

**Supported desktops**: Gnome; KDE plasma.

**Gnome shell version**: 40+

**Installation**:

1. Enable the Source Code repository in `software-properties-gtk`.

   [image: Software properties GTK]
2. Clone the repo:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/yilozt/mutter-rounded
   cd ./mutter-rounded/ubuntu_21.10
   ```
3. Run the installation:

   ```
   ./package.sh
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

**GitHub ID**: https://github.com/yilozt/mutter-rounded

**OMG Ubuntu**: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/01/mutter-rounded-transparent-blurred-look-on-ubuntu

> Mutter Rounded also allows you to render GTK windows transparent and apply a blur over what lays beneath. Although gsettings are enabled during install, I found using the nifty Mutter Rounded Settings app the easiest way to adjust blur intensity, opacity, and brightness.

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i'm asking about the theme not about the blurry shell

Comment: @BilalBentoumi Blurry shell? The name of the theme is **Mutter Rounded**.

Comment: @Someome Mutter Rounded is not a gnome theme, it's a window manager for GNOME, with rounded corners patch, regardless the theme you use

Comment: @BilalBentoumi Mutter Rounded IS a Gnome theme. The link to OMG Ubuntu is an evidence for the same.